# Is there a quick way to include all dependent items in a Sitecore package

Tags: packages, package-designer

Currently, I would add item by item in the `Package Designer`.

Is there a way to add just the page item and it would include all its dependent/associated items in the package, e.g.: Templates, Datasources, Renderings, Media etc.?

Using Sitecore v10.3

Comment: Have you explored the packaging tools included with Sitecore PowerShell extensions?

Comment: @MichaelWest I could not find anything about auto including associated items here. Could you please point me to the right documentation. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/modules/packaging

Answer (score 4):

You can create a package using the Scripts wizard. Here are the steps you can follow.

1. Right-click on the item and go to `Scripts -> Packaging -> Quick Download` Tree as package.

[image]

2. Add all the package details and in the OTHER tab, you can choose to include media, template, layout, and workflows. Choose these options to include items linked.

[image]

This way you can include the linked items.

Hope this is what you need.